# What is the difference between resolvconf, systemd-resolve, and avahi?

Tags: dns, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved, avahi, resolvconf

I'm currently working on a project that has required some DNS troubleshooting. However I am fairly new to the wonderful world of networking and I'm at a bit of a loss as to where to begin.

My specific problem probably belongs on the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange, so I'll avoid crossposting. Just looking for information here.

Looking for information, I was lead to the `resolv.conf(5)` file, `resolvconf(8)`, `systemd-resolve(1)`, and the beast that `avahi` appears to be.

My Raspberry Pi with Raspbian Buster appears to have `avahi-daemon` running.

My Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS has `systemd-resolved` AND `avahi-daemon`.

Does `resolvconf(8)` (man page only on Ubuntu) coordinate the two?

When is `/etc/resolv.conf` used/ignored?

*On Ubuntu:*

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf

# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search telus
```

*On Raspbian:*

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf

# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::1
```

Which utilities are responsible for this?

I don't really understand enough jargon to sift through the man pages and differentiate all these, and I'd love an explanation of how their roles are related.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you run a command such as `ping foobar` the system needs to work out how to convert `foobar` to an ip address.

Typically the first place it looks is `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

This might have a line such as:

```
hosts:          files dns mdns4
```

This tells the lookup routine to first look in "files", which is `/etc/hosts`.  If that doesn't find a match then it will then try to do a DNS lookup.  And if we still don't know the answer then it'll try to do a mDNS lookup.

The DNS lookup is where the system then looks at `/etc/resolv.conf`.  This tells it what DNS servers to look at.  On my machines I have this auto-configured by DHCP.

```
% cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
search mydomain
nameserver 10.0.0.1
nameserver 10.0.0.10
```

*How* `resolv.conf` is built can change, depending on the operating system, what optional components you got, other configuration entries, boot sequence...  In your case, on Ubuntu, you're running the systemd programs that configure this file to point to your local `systemd-resolved` and *that* will know how to talk to the real DNS servers.

On my primary servers, which have static IP addresses and no `systemd-resolved`, I manually edit this file.

Finally `mdns4` tells the routines to try asking `avahi-daemon` if it knows the name.

You can change the rules.  eg if `/etc/nsswitch.conf` just said:

```
hosts: files
```

then *only* the local `/etc/hosts` file is used.

Other entries are possible; eg `ldap` would make it do an LDAP lookup.

Comment: The `/etc/resolv.conf` file is just an implementation detail, it is not as essential as this answer implies. The definitive mechanism for applications to do name resolution is via library functions. These functions can make use of `resolv.conf` or they may not. Depending on how it is configured, systemd-resolved can make use of an existing `resolv.conf` provided by e.g. resolvconf(8), or it can *optionally* provide `/etc/resolv.conf` via a symlink to a systemd-resolved maintained version of the file. See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html

Comment: Everything is "implementation detail" if you go deep enough.  For example, `nsswitch.conf` is a libc feature and alternate libc libraries need follow this.  I described how glibc and the attendent NSS libraries work.  Ubuntu and Debian, out of box, do as I describe.

Comment: @StephenHarris What about `resolvconf`?