# APT - temporary failure in name resolution error

Tags: debian, networking, dns, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved

I have a really annoying & confusing issue about domain name resolution, focused only on `apt`/`apt-get` utility.

When I try `apt update`, it gives me (sorry in french)

```
root@myhostname:~# apt update
Err :1 http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/os/linux/raspbian/raspbian buster InRelease
  Erreur temporaire de résolution de « ftp.igh.cnrs.fr »
```

#### Tests & analysis

- Actually, DNS resolution is OK for all other tested resources

  - ✔ `nslookup ftp.igh.cnrs.fr` gives me

    ```
    Non-authoritative answer:
        ftp.igh.cnrs.fr canonical name = ftp4.igh.cnrs.fr.
        Name:   ftp4.igh.cnrs.fr
        Address: 193.50.6.155
    ```
  - ✔ I can also try `nslookup ftp.igh.cnrs.fr 8.8.8.8` with same result

  > Note: On these 2 first tests, I've got a strange long delay for response

  - ✔ `dig ftp.igh.cnrs.fr` gives me the same result
- ✔ I can run `wget` or `curl` commands successfully with the same URL

  ```
  root@myhostname:~# curl http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/os/linux/raspbian/raspbian
  <html>
  <head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
  <body bgcolor="white">
  <center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
  <hr><center>nginx</center>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

  ```
    wget http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/os/linux/raspbian/raspbian
  --2021-06-17 12:56:26--  http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/os/linux/raspbian/raspbian
  Résolution de ftp.igh.cnrs.fr (ftp.igh.cnrs.fr)… 193.50.6.155
  Connexion à ftp.igh.cnrs.fr (ftp.igh.cnrs.fr)|193.50.6.155|:80… connecté.
  requête HTTP transmise, en attente de la réponse… 301 Moved Permanently
  Emplacement : http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/os/linux/raspbian/raspbian/ [suivant]
  --2021-06-17 12:56:26--  http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/os/linux/raspbian/raspbian/
  Réutilisation de la connexion existante à ftp.igh.cnrs.fr:80.
  requête HTTP transmise, en attente de la réponse… 200 OK
  Taille : non indiqué [text/html]
  Sauvegarde en : « raspbian »
  ```
- ✔ If I try any *web command* such as `ssh`, it works again
- Next step, I thought about APT repositories availabiliy itself (if error message could be not reliable - you never know ;-))

  - Tries with others APT repository in `/etc/apt/sources.list` gives exactly the same bad result.
- About global system performance, I wondered if there can be any relation between slow system and dns resolution failure.
  I've also killed all heavy process. (such as a opened web browser).
  Here `top` example remaining result

  ```
  1 root      20   0   34824   8304   6496 S   1,3   0,9   0:26.26 systemd
    8596 root      20   0   10292   2876   2380 S   1,0   0,3   0:06.02 top
     120 root      20   0   32600  11760  10732 S   0,7   1,3   0:08.62 systemd-journal
     742 root      20   0    8144   3016   2836 S   0,7   0,3   0:00.55 check-vpn
  10878 root      20   0   10192   2792   2436 R   0,7   0,3   0:00.14 top
      12 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,3   0,0   0:02.68 rcu_sched
      13 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,3   0,0   0:00.02 migration/0
     110 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,3   0,0   0:00.19 kworker/3:2H-kblockd
     299 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,3   0,0   0:02.30 brcmf_wdog/mmc1
     380 message+  20   0    6664   3588   3084 S   0,3   0,4   0:10.36 dbus-daemon
     739 vnstat    20   0    2440    432    372 S   0,3   0,0   0:00.43 vnstatd
     761 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,3   0,0   0:03.51 kworker/u8:3-brcmf_wq/mmc1:0001:1
  10624 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,3   0,0   0:00.29 kworker/0:1-events
  10757 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,3   0,0   0:00.03 kworker/2:0-events
       2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.01 kthreadd
       3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_gp
       4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp
  ```

  I notice on this list a recurrent `kworker` process. Is it normal ?
  But globally, system seems not too high loaded

  ```
  Tasks: 141 total,   1 running, 139 sleeping,   1 stopped,   0 zombie
  %Cpu(s):  0,7 us,  1,0 sy,  0,0 ni, 98,1 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,2 si,  0,0 st
  MiB Mem :    872,7 total,    275,2 free,    123,7 used,    473,8 buff/cache
  MiB Swap:    100,0 total,    100,0 free,      0,0 used.    679,3 avail Mem
  ```
- Globally, I've found no other command line or graphic tool where dns resolution fails.
  !❓
- Global actions

  - I've tried to restart some services without any result
    `systemctl restart resolved`
     `systemctl restart systemd-resolved`
  - ⛔ Even when I restart network, it fails
    `systemctl restart networking`
  - ⛔ Even when I restart system, it fails

#### DNS Config Files

I've checked following files :

- `/etc/resolv.conf`

  ```
  nameserver 8.8.8.8
  option timeout:7
  ```
- `/etc/resolvconf/run/resolv.conf`

  ```
  nameserver 192.168.95.1
  nameserver 127.0.0.53
  search lan
  ```
- `/var/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`

  ```
  # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
  #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
  nameserver 192.168.95.1
  nameserver 127.0.0.53
  search lan
  ```
- `/etc/network/interfaces`

  ```
  auto eth0
  allow-hotplug eth0
  iface eth0 inet dhcp

  auto wlan0
  allow-hotplug wlan0
  iface wlan0 inet dhcp
       wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
  ```

  I've also checked with only one interface eth0, with static IP. Same result.

#### OS Config details

- I'm running Debian 10.9.  (with raspbian distro)
- Issue seems to trigger randomly on half of my devices (I've got ~100 appliances)

#### Workaround.

The only way that I've found to fix this issue is to reinstall resolvconf service

```bsh
apt purge -y openresolv resolvconf
wget http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/os/linux/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/r/resolvconf/resolvconf_1.79_all.deb
dpkg -i resolvconf_1.79_all.deb
systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service
```

But it is not reliable : I have to do this after every restart. Bad way...

Any idea on what's wrong on my system ?

Comment: My immediate thought is that the name resolution is taking too long and times out, generating the error in apt, while the other commands you showed gave it more time or tried more than once to resolve. What happens if you change that `option timeout:7` to something like `option timeout:30`?

Comment: I also note that your resolvconf (not resolve.conf) only probes 192.168.95.1 and 127.0.0.53, which I presume the first is your gateway/router, and the second is the resolver on your localhost. You may need to add 8.8.8.8 to our resolvconf template.

Comment: Thanks C.M. Indeed there were some misconfiguration due, I think, to file permissions issue detailed below

Comment: About timeout I tried this without any result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While digging in this strange situation, I've had an inspiration from articles telling about permissions. On first reading, no relation with my problem.

Anyway, I've checked file permissions on `/etc/resolv.conf`
Everything looks OK, except one particular point : `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symbolik link to `/opt/...` path

Even if permissions were looking right, I've tried to just copy the file instead of linking it. Then Alleluyah, it worked..

Do not ask me why `apt` checks this settings differently than global OS, I've no clue why. But that's the solution !

Comment: Actually, it is not. I did not fully engage my brain before... You are using the `resolvconf` _tool_ which generally takes control of the `resolv.conf` _file_, using it (and possibly re-writing it on the fly) as a fallback for software that is not `resolvconf` aware and only looks a `resolv.conf`. It appears the problem was indeed that somewhere, in either resolution method, you needed to make certain that an external nameserver (such as 8.8.8.8) was queried. For "why", this is a complex issue... Search the web for "resolvconf", looking a results with and without the '.'.

Comment: PS: Some links that _may_ help (_not_ checked deeply, just a quick search): https://askubuntu.com/questions/351168/diffrence-between-the-dns-setting-in-etc-resolv-conf-and-etc-network-interfaces | https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596434/what-is-the-difference-between-resolvconf-systemd-resolve-and-avahi | https://medium.com/@hsahu24/understanding-dns-resolution-and-resolv-conf-d17d1d64471c | https://wiki.debian.org/resolv.conf